# Error "Warning: file(...): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ..." when trying to read an uploaded file

Tags: php

I've read other posts about this error but I couldn't find the one that suit my case.

This is the problem: after uploading a content (text file) on a specific server path (I'm using an Apache local server), I can't read it with the `file()` function, except when the file is contained also in the main directory (`__DIR__`).

This is the problematic portion of the script:

```
$uploaddir = __DIR__.'/cbi_files/';
  if (!is_dir($uploaddir))
    mkdir($uploaddir);
  chmod($uploaddir, 0600);

  // Recovering temporary directory
  $userfile_tmp = $_FILES['cbi_file']['tmp_name'];

  // Recovering originary file's name
  $userfile_name = $_FILES['cbi_file']['name'];

  $count=0;
  $operazione = 0;
  $file_caricati = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['cbi_file']['name'] as $filename) {
        $destination = $uploaddir;
        $origin = $_FILES['cbi_file']['tmp_name'][$count];
        $count++;
        $destination = $destination.basename($filename);
        // moving files from temporary directory to destination
        $operazione = move_uploaded_file($origin, $destination);
        $file_caricati[] = $filename;
    }

$file_cbi = array();
$righe = array();

if (is_dir($uploaddir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($uploaddir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
          if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            $righe = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); // I get the error on this line
            $last_row = count($righe)-1;
            include(__DIR__.'/scriptCBI.php');
            $file_cbi[] = array(
                            'nome_file' => $file,
                            'codice_RH' => $righe[0],
                            'codice_EF' => $righe[$last_row],
                            'recs' => $rec_array
                        );
          }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

I get the error if I keep the file only in `$uploaddir = __DIR__'/cbi_files/'`, but if I keep it both in this directory and in the main directory (`__DIR__`) it works properly.
How's that possible?

Comment: what does `echo $uploaddir` give? `__DIR__` has a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.

Comment: This is what I've got: "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\php\serverweb\scriptCBI\altra_strutt/cbi_files/"